# Where does this undefined value come from?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare two arrays and return a new array with any items only found in one of the two given arrays.

e.g. Result of comparing `[1,2,3,4]` and `[1,2,3]` should be: `[4]`.

Problem is that, I get `'undefined'` element after loop is executed.

```
function diff(arr1, arr2){
    var newArr = [];
    for(i=arr1[0]; i<=arr1.length; i++){
      if(arr2.indexOf(arr1[i])=== -1){ 
        newArr.push(arr1[i]);
      }
    }
    console.log(newArr);
};

diff([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3]);
```

result of this is `[4, undefined]`. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `i=arr1[0]` is probably not what you want

Comment: Looping until `<= length` is a classic off-by-one error as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop has been defined incorrectly. It should start at `i=0` and run until `i<arr1.length`

```
function diff(arr1, arr2){
    var newArr = [];
    for(i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
      if(arr2.indexOf(arr1[i])=== -1){ 
        newArr.push(arr1[i]);
      }
    }
    console.log(newArr);
};
```

By running until `i<=arr1.length` you are attempting to iterate once more than is needed, resulting in the addition of the final undefined value in the results array. As Mario Garcia says in comments, in the final iteration the loop will try to access `arr[4]` which doesn't exist, so is therefore undefined.

Comment: To be clear: arr1[4] = undefined, and since arr2 does not containt "undefinned", your function adds it to newArr. Just fix your loop indexes as said above

Comment: Thanks, I need sleep I guess :)

Comment: Not a problem! Easy mistakes to make

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is wrong because your iterator doesn't start from 0 (to match the first array element), but from the value of the array at the index zero (which is number 1 in your case, but could be pretty much anything); and then you go out of index range when the iterator reaches the length of an array, in your case it's 4, and **arr1[4] is undefined**.

After fixing the loop start value and condition, we get:

```js
function diff(arr1, arr2){
    var newArr = [];
    for(i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
      if(arr2.indexOf(arr1[i])=== -1){ 
        newArr.push(arr1[i]);
      }
    }
    alert(newArr);
};

diff([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3]); // 4
diff([1,2,3,4,5], [1,3]); // 2, 4, 5
```